# How to call function defined inside "pageshow" events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have defined the function in `pageshow` event but when trying to call that function I am getting error function is not defined. whats the reason? How can I call a function? Please let me know

```
 $(document).on('pageshow',"#summaryDetailPg", function() {
    $("#uploadButton").removeClass('ui-disabled');
    $("#sendEmailButton").removeClass('ui-disabled');
    riskAssessmentCheckedNotesCountStatus = 0;
    riskAssessmentCheckedCount = 0;
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Loading...", false);
    getSiteRequiredInfo();
    getBriefRequiredInfo();
    getCustomerRequiredInfo();

    $("#summaryDetailPgDiscipline").empty().append("").trigger('create');

    getSystemDetailSiteInfo();
    getSystemDetailCustomerInfo();
    getSystemDetailRiskInfo();
    getSystemDetailDisciplineInfo();
    getSignature();
    getRiskAssessmentCheckedCount();

    function GetStatus()
    {
         if (window.localStorage.getItem("userrole").indexOf("SendPdfToCustomer") != -1) {
        //console.log("grandTotalCostProposal:::",+grandTotalCostProposal);
       // console.log("window.localStorage.getInternal Notes:"+ window.localStorage.getItem("internalNotesValues"));

        console.log("window.localStorage.userProposalReview0:::"+window.localStorage.getItem("userProposalReview"));
        console.log("grandTotalCostProposal"+grandTotalCostProposal);
        //quote price is greater than totalRevenue Limit
        if((grandTotalCostProposal >  window.localStorage.getItem("userProposalReview")) && $('#enq6').val().length >0)
       {
          console.log("if block condition inside");
            $('#sendToOfficeAndCustomer').hide();
            $('#sendToOfficeAndCustomer').addClass('ui-disabled');
       }
    else
       {
       $('#sendToOfficeAndCustomer').show();
       }

        $('#sendToOfficeAndCustomer').off("click").on("click", function () {
           // checkConnection();
             $("#sendEmailButton").removeClass('ui-disabled');
             pdfFlag = "mail";
             uploadDataType = "office";
             $.mobile.changePage("#sendToEmailForm",null,true,true);
            //if quote price is lesser than button enable


        });

     else {
        alert("sendPdfToCustomer is equal -1");
        $('#sendToOfficeAndCustomer').hide();
    }
    }
```

unable to call function `GetStatus()`

Comment: Move the function outside of the event handler?

Comment: yes ok  fine now its working